# Maven. Зависимость дочерних модулей модулей

Tags: java, maven

Как приавильно указать зависимость между дочерними модулями? У меня есть модуль server и client. Второй зависит от первого. Но при сборке возникает ошибка:

```
Failed to execute goal on project client: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.vladhuk:client:jar:0.9-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.vladhuk:server:jar:0.9-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

Поискав в интернете, решение нашел только для тех, кто подключает зависимости из публичных репозиториев. В моем же случае это просто соседние модули.

Comment: Выполните mvn install для модуля, который устанавливаете в качестве зависимости для другого модуля. Эта команда "положит" его в локальный репозиторий.

Comment: @Vladimir помогло) Еще, правда, требовалось выполнить эту команду для родительского модуля.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить оба модуля в ["реактор"](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html). Таким образом вы гарантируете, что при сборке зависимости будут браться из директории build модуля (в реакторе прописывается релятивный путь), а не из репозиториев. Даже если вы не будете выполнять шаг `install`, зависимости всё равно будут найдены.

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Simple Parent Project</name>

    <modules>
        <module>example-server</module>
        <module>example-parent</module>
    </modules>
<!- всё остальное, что общее для всего проекта - зависимости, плагины, и так далее -->
</project>
```

Comment: Как добавить модули в реактор? Если это означает: прописать их в тэг <modules>, то у меня они прописаны, и тем не менее все равно приходится выполнять install.

Comment: ну что-то надо точно запускать, собрать же нужно, джава не умеет зависеть от исходников. Просто не обязательно `install`,  можно, например, `package`. Ну, и конечно не надо запускать на все по отдельности, можно только на parent запустить.